Creating a dynamic array formula with INDEX MATCH
I'm a teacher and I've tried to make an Excel spreadhseet that can automatically pick out a specified number of random keywords and their corresponding definitions from a master list:

The number of keywords and definitions to be output are specified in cell B2 of the Vocab Quiz sheet:

Then the array formula in cell D3 spits out the ID's for the specified number of entries (e.g. 9 keywords). This array formula will update to automatically resize the number of entries depending on how many you request.
I then want to use an INDEX MATCH formula: (=INDEX('Vocab list'!B:B,MATCH('Vocab Quiz'!D3,'Vocab list'!A:A,0),SEQUENCE('Vocab Quiz'!$B$2))) to lookup and match the ID against it's corresponding keyword from the master list, whilst dynamically adjusting to the size of the number of keywords requested.
INDEX MATCH formula:

The issue I'm having is that the array is continually using the lookup value for cell D3, resulting in a #REF! error, and what I really want is for the INDEX MATCH array formula to lookup the next row down for the length of the dynamic array (i.e. D4, D5,...D11).
I know the array formula is constantly referring to cell D3 because that's where I've told it to look, but if I were to drag the formula down manually, using autofil it would change the 'D3' reference to the next row as there's no $ locking in in place. I was hoping that's what the array would also do, but evidently not.
What do I need to change to get the array to work as I would like it to?

What version of Excel are you using?

You can use the (relatively) new CHOOSEROWS function to get your results.
Your formula will be something like:
=CHOOSEROWS('Vocab list'!B:B,MATCH('Vocab Quiz'!D3#,'Vocab list'!A:A,0))

INDEX and MATCH functions will suffice:
=INDEX('Vocab list'!B:C, MATCH('Vocab Quiz'!D3#, 'Vocab list'!A:A,0),{1,2})

@MGonet this comment should be an answer - the solution revolves around the use of the # after D3 rather than anything else.

Using XLOOKUP, although it requires 2 formulas:
=XLOOKUP($D$3#;'Vocab List'!$A$2:$A$54;'Vocab List'!B2:B54;"")
and drag one to the right:
=XLOOKUP($D$3#;'Vocab List'!$A$2:$A$30;'Vocab List'!C2:C30;"")


This is what you could have done using INDEX()+MATCH()/XMATCH()+MATCH()/XMATCH() however, using CHOOSEROWS() with XMATCH() would be suffice:


=INDEX('Vocab list'!B:C,
 XMATCH('Vocab Quiz'!D3#,'Vocab list'!A:A),
 XMATCH('Vocab Quiz'!E2:F2,'Vocab list'!B1:C1))


Or, Using CHOOSEROWS()+XMATCH() -- this assumes the headers in the target cells are not going to altered and will remain as is like the source.


=CHOOSEROWS('Vocab list'!B:C,XMATCH('Vocab Quiz'!D3#,'Vocab list'!A:A))


